# How to show all foreign key attribute in Django template?

Tags: python, django-models

I want to fetch all the foreignkey table's attribute and show it in my HTML template. Here is my code in models, views and in the template:

***models.py***:

```
class OrderDashboard(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
    single_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, default=1)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    thumb = models.ImageField()
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class OrderScenario(models.Model):
    webshop = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.ForeignKey(OrderDashboard, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    order_qty = models.TextField(max_length=10)
    order_date = models.DateField()
    current_status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ticket = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    remark = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Scenario"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.webshop
```

***Views.py***:

```
def single_slug(request, single_slug):
   report = OrderDashboard.objects.get(single_slug=single_slug)
   return render(request, 'order_dashboard/report.html', {'report': report,
                                                          'OrderScenario': OrderScenario.objects.all})
```

I only want to view all the scenarios added in `OrderScenario` with respect to `Title` in `OrderDashboard`.

Comment: So what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **backward relationship** here; if you are passing the `slug` through the url, you can use:

**views.py**:

```
def single_slug(request, slug):  # why you have self as the first argument?
   report = OrderDashboard.objects.get(single_slug=slug)
   return render(request, 'order_dashboard/report.html', {'report': report}
```

**report.html**:

```
{{ report.title }}
</p>Order Scenarios:</p>
{% for scenario in report.orderscenario_set.all %}
{{ scenario }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi @pedram,
Woops  that 'self' was my bad. and your worked pefectly. Thanks for the help :)